# Slowness of Jasper Studio vs Jasper Server

Tags: jasperserver

I am facing a performance issue with jasper server. My query is for `CrossTab`. Query works fine in Toad as well as in jasper studio but it's execution is very slow in jasper server and sometimes it even fail with connection timeout.

I can't understand what is the reason for this behavior. Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Query performance in jasper server depends on various factors but to get a quick idea of where the bottle neck might be in case of CrossTab (AdHoc functionality), follow these steps:

Login to JasperReport server through web UI (login as superuser) and take a look at Manage => Server Setings => Ad Hoc Cache. Here, analyze Query and Fetch column values.

1. Query (msec)
   It shows the time from when query was sent to the db until the first row was received. If this is slow then one possible improvement would be to index some fields in the underlying database query. If you are using derived tables then trying switching to actual tables because derived tables are sub-queries/sub-selects and are intensive performance wise.
2. Fetch (msec)
   Time from when first row was received until the last
   row was received. If this is slow there might be a network
   bottleneck. Try to set the fetch size in the jasperreports.properties
   file to modify the number of rows to fetch at a time. Optimizing this can reduce the number of trips to the underlying database.